# Symfony: JQuery Collection Plugin doesn't work (Can't apply necessary form theme)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I am trying to build a symfony form with collections, for adding and removing I am trying to use the symfony jquery collection plugin.

To make the plugin work I need to apply a form theme, but not matter what I try the following lines don't work.

```
                    {% form_theme userSettings 'jquery.collection.html.twig' %}
                    {{ form(userSettings) }}
```